# Convert multiple column headers to Values in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

So my data is imported from excel in this format

```
                alpha 
         beta           gamma 
    var1 var2 var3 var1 var2 var3  
1     21   50    5   22   48    6        
2     27   50    5   24   48    6        
3     26   50    5   28   48    6    
4     25   50    5   28   48    6
```

and i want to convert it to this format

```
    var1 var2 var3  var4 var5  
1     21   50    5  alpha beta            
2     27   50    5  alpha beta            
3     26   50    5  alpha beta      
4     25   50    5  alpha beta 
5     22   48    6  alpha gamma
6     24   48    6  alpha gamma
7     28   48    6  alpha gamma
8     28   48    6  alpha gamma
```

What could be a possible way to do that in R. Notice that alpha is 1st level header, beta and gamma are a second level headers but imported as a row in R

Here's the dput(file)

```
    structure(list(X.group.age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("", "19-15", 
"24-20", "29-25", "34-30", "39-35", "44-40", "49-45", "54-50", 
"59-55", "64-60"), class = "factor"), X1999. = structure(c(12L, 
11L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("132486", 
"187238", "226157", "25755", "277822", "351166", "408307", "435447", 
"53084", "84800", "MALE", "BRITISH"), class = "factor"), 
    X. = structure(c(1L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
    8L, 4L), .Label = c("", "102978", "11871", "1828", "24871", 
    "3720", "4136", "4526", "49072", "65049", "78375", "إناث"
    ), class = "factor"), X..1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "NA", "TOTAL"
    ), class = "factor"), X..2 = structure(c(12L, 11L, 9L, 2L, 
    7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("171302", "204856", 
    "20740", "318726", "40116", "493643", "576850", "612027", 
    "8415", "93130", "MALE", "USA"), class = "factor"), 
    X..3 = structure(c(1L, 12L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 
    9L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("", "158711", "18484", "2038", "2410", 
    "37816", "43444", "5089", "7134", "78785", "90155", "FEMALE"
    ), class = "factor"), X..4 = structure(c(1L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 
    10L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 5L), .Label = c("", "100264", 
    "13504", "189786", "23150", "242672", "362170", "42154", 
    "583798", "655635", "770738", "TOTAL"), class = "factor"), 
    X2000. = structure(c(12L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
    1L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("132830", "201634", "225389", "289188", 
    "364795", "38815", "419225", "443670", "59708", "97645", 
    "MALE", "BRITISH"), class = "factor"), X..5 = structure(c(1L, 
    12L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 11L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
    "103289", "14099", "2033", "27027", "3327", "4341", "49512", 
    "52910", "6867", "85007", "FEMALE"), class = "factor"), 
    X..6 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "NA", "TOTAL"), class = "factor"), 
    X..7 = structure(c(12L, 11L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 
    2L, 10L, 8L), .Label = c("115574", "177250", "19787", "267819", 
    "326709", "465506", "494696", "51245", "544286", "92696", 
    "male", "USA"), class = "factor"), X..8 = structure(c(1L, 
    12L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
    "106279", "1476", "3050", "32104", "36447", "52824", "6407", 
    "7497", "75029", "96487", "female"), class = "factor"), 
    X..9 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "NA", "Total"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X.group.age", 
"X1999.", "X.", "X..1", "X..2", "X..3", "X..4", "X2000.", "X..5", 
"X..6", "X..7", "X..8", "X..9"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post `dput(yourexample)` so as to know the structure of the data?  Or have you read the data in R?

Comment: It may be better to read the dataset by skipping the first two lines i.e. `dat <- read.csv("yourfile.csv", skip=2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to avoid conversion of all columns to `factor/character`.  Then read the 1st two lines

Comment: but then my problem would be how to link alpha values to alpha and beta values to beta. look at my table, my main problem is how to deal with multiple headers from an excel sheet

Comment: Remove the multiple headers from the excel sheet, and change the header so it contains all info. And use package `reshape` to restructure your data according to your specs.

Answer (score 0):

When you have your header fixed in Excel, you can do as follows, to reshape your data. (example with random data).

```
library(reshape2)

dt <- data.frame(id = 1:100
                 ,beta_var1 = rnorm(100,mean = 4, sd = 2)
                 , beta_var2 = rnorm(100,mean = 7, sd = 3)
                 , gamma_var1 = rnorm(100,mean = 5, sd = 2)
                 , gamma_var2 = rnorm(100,mean = 5, sd = 3))
head(dt)

st1 <- melt(dt, id.vars = 'id')
head(st1)

st2 <- transform(st1, n = colsplit(st1$variable,"_", c("letter","var")))
head(st2)

st3 <- dcast(st2, id + n.letter ~ n.var)
head(st3)
```

source

```
> head(dt)
id  beta_var1 beta_var2 gamma_var1 gamma_var2
1  1 0.09267697  8.756578   2.350164   7.774297
2  2 0.97311566  8.097634   9.793237   2.261395
3  3 2.08363376  7.566973   7.053660   3.725915
4  4 2.97215984 10.934154   4.767223   5.779393
5  5 2.21449327 11.794902   6.016574   5.998344
6  6 3.81294082  8.373939   5.257709   2.481696
```

output

```
> head(st3)
id n.letter       var1     var2
1  1     beta 0.09267697 8.756578
2  1    gamma 2.35016370 7.774297
3  2     beta 0.97311566 8.097634
4  2    gamma 9.79323667 2.261395
5  3     beta 2.08363376 7.566973
6  3    gamma 7.05365982 3.725915
```